# Integrating game center into cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d, game-center

I have a Cocos 2d game in which I want to have achievements and a leader-board. What are the steps I would need to take?

Thanks

P.S All of the tutorials I have found are outdated. So please write instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to know how far in the process you are.

If you haven't already registered your app and set up your leaderboards and achievements through iTunes Connect, then you should read through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23189/whats-new-with-game-center-in-ios-6).

If you have, then let us know exactly what you're stuck on.

Comment: I tried it but its really for ios 6. Im looking for an ios 4 and up solution

Comment: Probably should have clarified what 'outdated' meant. There are other tutorials available on raywenderlich.com regarding game center integration (for ios4+)

Comment: the portion about itunes connect was dead on. it was just the actual code that I had a problem with